# xampp don't start Tomcat while others perfectly start

Tags: tomcat, web, xampp

[XAMPP Control Panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMO1M.jpg)

I already installed jdk 1.8 and correctly add the path to system variable.
please help me.

```
1:53:31 AM  [Tomcat]    Attempting to start Tomcat service...
1:55:56 AM  [Tomcat]    Problem detected!
1:55:56 AM  [Tomcat]    Port 8080 in use by ""C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice"!
1:55:56 AM  [Tomcat]    Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
1:55:56 AM  [Tomcat]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
1:55:56 AM  [Tomcat]    or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
1:55:56 AM  [Tomcat]    Attempting to start Tomcat service...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your port is already in use, change the port and try again it should work. Click on config next to Tomcat and change the port number, change it something else from 8080.

You can also click on Config on the top right and then click on Service and Port settings there go to the Tomcat tab and change the port from 8080 to something like 8081.

Comment: I have change the prot from 80 to 81 but still it throw me same error. Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!

Answer (score 2):

The Port 8080 is already occuped by another tool (like Jira or Skype), if your are behind xampp, you click on =>control panel => Config => Service and port setting => and you change the port of tomcat to something like 8081 or 8082

Answer (score 0):

On *XAMPP control panel* click **config** in the apache row => **httpd.config** => in that find and change **Listen 8070** *to* **Listen 8081**, then your problem is solved.
But to open the phpmyadmin or htdocs folder you have to use localhost:8081/ instead of localhost/